# Powershell connection from specific local IP Address

Tags: powershell, network-programming

I have a **local computer** with multiple ip addresses:
192.168.1.1 <-- **I want to use this ip**
192.168.1.2

From the **local computer** I want to start a PowerShell session to a **remote server**:
192.168.1.12

Is there any way to start a PSSession using a specific local ip address?
Something like this:

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 192.168.1.12 -Credential myUserName **-UseLocalIP=192.168.1.1**